# Inverse of idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inverse

let M $\in$ M<sub>n</sub>(R) be a matrix such that M<sup>2</sup> - M = 0, Then find M<sup>-1</sup> (M inverse)?

My approach is:-
Let M be an invertible matrix,
$\Rightarrow$ M x M<sup>-1</sup> = I<sub>n</sub>, where I<sub>n</sub> is identity matrix of order n.
So, M<sup>2</sup> - M = 0, $\Rightarrow$ M<sup>2</sup> = M,
$\Rightarrow$ M is an Idempotent Matrix. Now, multiple both sides with M<sup>-1</sup>
$\Rightarrow$  M<sup>2</sup> x M<sup>-1</sup> = M x M<sup>-1</sup>
$\Rightarrow$ M = I<sub>n</sub>,
$\Rightarrow$ M<sup>2</sup> = I<sub>n</sub>

But I am unable to proceed further to calculate the matrix. I don't know what steps I have follow to calculate  M<sup>-1</sup> of M.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Supposing $M$ is invertible, multiply that last equation by $M^{-1}$ to get $M=M^{-1}=I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $M^2-M=0$, then , $M^2=M$.
If $M$ is invertible then,$M=I$. Inverse of an identity matrix is identity matrix. Hence $M^{-1}=M=I$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $M$ is idempotent if $M^{2}=M$. If you let $M$ be an invertible idempotent matrix, then $M^{-1}$ exists and satisfies $M^{-1}M=I_{n}$ where $I_{n}$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Now $M^{2}=M \Leftrightarrow M^{-1}M^{2}=M^{-1}M$. Because $M^{-1}M=I_{n}$ thus we obtain $M=I_{n}$. Now, since $M=I_{n}$, therefore $M^{-1}=I_{n}$.